# How to use flex to wrap items in rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to wrap div containers so that they go into rows of two items max, and the last div would take over the whole length since it's the only item in a row.

I basically want it to look like this:
[image: template]

This is what I get for now:
[image: current]

```css
#fifth-section {
  background-color: #1f80a9;
  color: #fff;
}

.fifth-section-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.fifth-section-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section id="fifth-section">
  <h1 class="fifth-section-header">User Experience</h1>
  <div class="fifth-section-container">
    <div class="users-1">
      <h5>CEO and VP Human Resources</h5>
      <p>Want a system to track the real time status of key performance objectives for purposes of paying bonuses to employees.
        ROCalytics will provide a real time and up to date documentation trail of completion status, accessible at any
        time for purposes of evaluating performance.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ux-image">
      <img src="img/rocalytics-app.png" alt="rocalytics app image">
    </div>
    <div class="users-2">
      <h5>Marketing VP</h5>
      <p>Fom a global e-commerce marketplace, in which revenue growth is driven by aggressive marketing campaigns developed
        at HQ and executed globally, wants a real time solution to understand the progress of campaign development at the
        HQ level as well as track the field implementation. This will provide a complete picture of marketing campaign
        effectiveness.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="users-3"></div>
    <div class="users-4"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to specify the behavior of the children like so:

```css
#fifth-section {
  background-color: #1f80a9;
  color: #fff;
}

.fifth-section-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.fifth-section-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fifth-section-container > div {
  /* from l2r: 1 = expand automatically, 0 = don't shrink, 50% = basis length of items */
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

/* alternative in expanded form: */
/*.fifth-section-container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}*/
```

```html
<section id="fifth-section">
  <h1 class="fifth-section-header">User Experience</h1>
  <div class="fifth-section-container">
    <div class="users-1">
      <h5>CEO and VP Human Resources</h5>
      <p>Want a system to track the real time status of key performance objectives for purposes of paying bonuses to employees.
        ROCalytics will provide a real time and up to date documentation trail of completion status, accessible at any
        time for purposes of evaluating performance.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ux-image">
      <img src="img/rocalytics-app.png" alt="rocalytics app image">
    </div>
    <div class="users-2">
      <h5>Marketing VP</h5>
      <p>Fom a global e-commerce marketplace, in which revenue growth is driven by aggressive marketing campaigns developed
        at HQ and executed globally, wants a real time solution to understand the progress of campaign development at the
        HQ level as well as track the field implementation. This will provide a complete picture of marketing campaign
        effectiveness.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="users-3">filler</div>
    <div class="users-4"><h5>full row example</h5><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
  </div>
</section>
```